# How to take mean of n-dimensional vector along a given axis?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, average

I'm trying to take the mean of a given n-dimensional vector along one of its axes. For example,

$\mu_2\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 2 \\
2 & 3 & 4 \\
4 & 4 & 2
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac {1 + 2 + 2} 3 \\
\frac {2 + 3 + 4} 3 \\
\frac {4 + 4 + 2} 3 
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac 5 3 \\
 3 \\
 \frac 3 {10}
\end{bmatrix}$

Here I've taken the mean of the first vector along its second axis. It's a simple-to-understand process for 1- and 2-D vectors, but anything beyond is hard to perceive, let alone calculate.

Is there some formula for accomplishing this for any vector of shape $(\alpha, \beta, \chi...)$?

Comment: It sounds like you just want to flatten the array in one direction, so e.g. taking the mean of a 4x5x6 array along its second axis would give you a 4x6 array whose $(i,j)$'th entry is the mean of the five input entries $a_{i,1,j}, \dots, a_{1,5,j}$.

Comment: @Karl that sounds right. Is there a generic way to achieve that for a matrix with an unknown number of dimensions?

Comment: This is a built-in function in languages like Julia. For example $\;\tt{mean(M,dims=2)}\,$ will replicate the calculation above. To do it manually, simply sum over the index along the desired axis and divide by the dimension of that axis. Here's an example for the mean along the $2^{nd}$ axis of a $3^{rd}$ order tensor
$$\mu_{ik} = \frac 1n\sum_{j=1}^nM_{ijk} \\$$ Notice that the result is a tensor of order one less than the starting tensor.